# Changing background of a particular row of Listview

Tags: android, listview

I am developing an application that has list of items and on selecting particular item from list view, i want to change the background color of that selected whole row, but on implementing this my all rows background color changed. Please somebody help me . Thanks in Advace. Here is my Adaptor.xml

```
 public class Adaptor_ListItem extends ArrayAdapter<MyItem> {
        public Context mContext;
        public ArrayList<MyItem> listItem;
        public LayoutInflater inflater;
        public int position1=-1;

        public Adaptor_ListItem(Context context, int resource, List<MyItem> list,
                int selectedPos) {
            super(context, resource, list);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            mContext = context;
            listItem = (ArrayList<MyItem>) list;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            position1 = selectedPos;
        } // method ends

        public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View holder = convertView;
            if (holder == null) {
                holder = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adaptor_itemlist, null);
            }
            if (listItem.size() != 0) {

                TextView txtName = (TextView) holder
                        .findViewById(R.id.ListItem_txtName);
                TextView txtDays = (TextView) holder
                        .findViewById(R.id.ListItem_txtDays);
                TextView txtRecurring = (TextView) holder
                        .findViewById(R.id.ListItem_txtRecuring);
                MyItem objItem = listItem.get(pos);
                if (objItem != null) {
                    String strName = objItem.itemName;
                    String strRecurring = objItem.recurring + "";
                    String strDays = objItem.days;
                    int itemId = objItem.itemId;
                    // for checking which item has notified
                    if ((pos== position1) && holder!=null ) {
                        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) holder
                                .findViewById(R.id.linearListItem);
                        txtName.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        txtDays.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        txtRecurring.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        System.out.println("Adaptor_ListItem.getView()//// method block");
                    }
                    if (strDays == null) {
                        txtName.setText(strName);
                        txtDays.setText("0 Days");
                        txtRecurring.setText(strRecurring + "");
                    } else {
                        txtName.setText(strName);
                        txtDays.setText(strDays + " Days");
                        txtRecurring.setText(strRecurring + "");

                    }

                }
            }
            return holder;
        }// method ends
    } // final class ends
```

Answer (score 0):

Just mention the background for main layout in `adaptor_itemlist.xml` file.

write the selector for background:

`item_selector.xml:`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/red"></item>
<item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@android:color/white"></item>

</selector>
```

Apply this file to the background of main layout in `adapter_itemlist.xml`

use bellow code:

```
linearLayout.setSelected(true);
```

instead of:

```
txtName.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
txtDays.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
txtRecurring.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: actually this is not i required,

Comment: Shayan pourvatan: actually i am adding notification for particular item of  listview , when notifcation is recieved i am opening same activity which has this listview  via intent and adding position of selected row to this intent, when this activity opens i get this position and pass it to adaptor constructor for setting some background color to this row , which i am doing by this condition if(pos==position1), but it changes the background color of all rows, this is my problem it should change the background color of only selected row.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in getview  in your custom adapter .

```
listTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#aaaaaa"));
```

Comment: background color is changing in my code but not for single row , it is changing for all rows, that is my actual problem

Comment: i mean to you say that all row have different bg color.right?

Comment: please take array of color and pass is into your custom adapter base on your position..

Comment: my all rows same background color but condition if(pos== position1) becomes true, than only that specific row background color should change

Answer (score 0):

use following code instead of your code:

```
     public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        ViewHolder Holder;

    if (v == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adaptor_itemlist, null);

            Holder = new ViewHolder();

            Holder.txtName = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.ListItem_txtName);
            Holder.txtDays = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.ListItem_txtDays);
            Holder.txtRecurring = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.ListItem_txtRecuring);
            MyItem objItem = listItem.get(pos);
            v.setTag(Holder);
            }
      else
         holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();

      if (objItem != null) {
                String strName = objItem.itemName;
                String strRecurring = objItem.recurring + "";
                String strDays = objItem.days;
                int itemId = objItem.itemId;
                // for checking which item has notified
                if ((pos== position1)) {
                    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) v
                            .findViewById(R.id.linearListItem);
                    Holder.txtName.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    Holder.txtDays.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    Holder.txtRecurring.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    System.out.println("Adaptor_ListItem.getView()//// method block");
                }
        else
       {
                  // set Default Value
               }
                if (strDays.equals(null)) {
                    Holder.txtName.setText(strName);
                    Holder.txtDays.setText("0 Days");
                    Holder.txtRecurring.setText(strRecurring + "");
                } else {
                    Holder.txtName.setText(strName);
                    Holder.txtDays.setText(strDays + " Days");
                    Holder.txtRecurring.setText(strRecurring + "");

                }


        }
        return v;
    }// method ends
} // final class ends
```

and ViewHolder class is:

```
 public static class ViewHolder()
 {
    public TextView txtName , txtDays, txtRecurring;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int [] arrayColors={Color.GREEN,Color.BLUE,Color.Red}
```

this below line call in your getview method of your adapter.

```
yourView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(arrayColors[pos]));
```

Comment: don't you think this get `IndexOut` in `arrayColors`? you put only three item in your array but `pos` maybe bigger than 3.

Comment: this is base on requirement howmany color are there in array..this is not problem...anyone can understand which size of array is required for my app.?

Comment: and in dynamic list how do you know number of color?`pos` value can be 0-list.size

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the background color back to the original color when (pos!=position1) .. or the else clause for your if (pos=position1)  statement.  Right now what's happening is that once you set the list item to red, it gets recycled to another row, but it stays red because it never got unset in the new getView() call.

```
               int feedbackColor = Color.WHITE;  // or whatever your base color is
               if ((pos== position1) && holder!=null ) {
                    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) holder
                            .findViewById(R.id.linearListItem);
                    feedbackColor = Color.RED;

                }
                txtName.setBackgroundColor(feedbackColor);
                txtDays.setBackgroundColor(feedbackColor);
                txtRecurring.setBackgroundColor(feedbackColor);
```